# Unable to update an entity in azure table storage using azure node.js sdk

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-table-storage

I am using node-v0.8.21. And am using azure node.js sdk to handle azure table storage operations. It works fine in most cases but when the PartitionKey of my table has spaces in it then updating that entity throws up an error as shown below.

```
{ [Error: [object Object]]
  code: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  message:
   { _: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Autho
rization header is formed correctly including the signature.',
     '$': { 'xml:lang': 'en-US' } } }
```

Any idea on how i can fix it?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked OK for me. Can you share some code or actual data where update is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because of the node.js version as well as some missing azure node modules. I installed  0.8.4 node.js version and re installed the azure node modules with npm install azure command and it started working fine.